# Невозможно подключиться к серверу с другого IP

Tags: java, android, сервер

Привет! Собрал небольшой "сервер" на Android, используя `NanoHTTPD`. Код активити:

```
    mWifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
    int ipAddress = mWifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress();

    SERVER_IP = String.format("%d.%d.%d.%d", (ipAddress & 0xff), (ipAddress >> 8 & 0xff),
                              (ipAddress >> 16 & 0xff), (ipAddress >> 24 & 0xff));

    try
    {
        mServer = new MyServer(SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT);
        mServer.start();

        log("Server started! Please visit:");
        log("http://" + SERVER_IP + ":" + SERVER_PORT);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log("Shit! Can't start server!");
        for (StackTraceElement ste : ex.getStackTrace())
        {
            log(ste.toString());
        }
    }
```

Код сервера:

```
public class MyServer extends NanoHTTPD
{
    public MyServer(String address, int port)
    {
        super(address, port);
    }

    @Override
    public NanoHTTPD.Response serve(String uri, NanoHTTPD.Method method, Map<String, String> headers, Map<String, String> parms, Map<String, String> files)
    {
        MainActivity.log("Incoming " + method.toString() + " request!");

        String html = "<html><body><h1>Hello, World</h1></body></html>";

        return newFixedLengthResponse(html);
    }
}
```

После запуска приложения в логах появляется надпись:

```
Server started! Please visit:
http://192.168.1.3:1450
```

С другого устройства в той же WiFi сети захожу на страницу, показывается `Hello, world!`, а на "сервере" в логах `Incoming GET request!`

Но как только я переключаю на "клиенте" WiFi сеть и пытаюсь сделать запрос на "сервер" `http://мой.внешний.статический.ip:1450`, то во всех браузерах мгновенно выводится ошибка `ECONNREFUSED (Connection Refused)`. В домашней сети я открыл порты `1400-1500` для "сервера" и сделал перенаправление с порта `80` на порт `1450` (чтобы можно было не вводить порт). NAT и прочие провайдерские ограничения отсутствуют.

Как можно исправить эту ошибку?

Comment: Вопрос нужно задавать там, где сетевые администраторы тусуются. Ни к Java, ни к Android он отношения не имеет.

Comment: Раз сервер байндится на 192.168.1.3, то NAT у Вас все-таки есть!

Comment: `Вопрос нужно задавать там, где сетевые администраторы тусуются.`

Напоминаю:

`Stack Overflow на русском - это сообщество профессиональных разработчиков программного обеспечения, энтузиастов программирования и системных администраторов.`

[Источник](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
`Ни к Java, ни к Android он отношения не имеет.`
ИМХО, код я написал как раз таки на Java и запустил я его на Android, а значит, что теги я выставил верно.

Comment: `<режим зануды>`Кстати, раз проблему решили, то можете отметить вопрос как отвеченный.`</режим зануды>`

Comment: @NickVolynkin `<режим_зануды тип="ответ">`Я не могу отметить свой ответ как правильный сразу, нужно подождать полтора дня.`</режим_зануды>`

Comment: @SuperCreeper =) я думал, ответ Eugene считается за решение.

Answer (score 4):

Если вы сделали перенаправление с 80 на 1450, то укажите роутеру на какой IP перенаправлять.
И заходите http://мой.внешний.статический.ip:80 тогда.
Порты 1400-1500 можете закрыть, раз у Вас перенаправление.
И убедитесь, что 80 порт открыт для входящих соединений.

Comment: проблему решил, за помощь спасибо! :)

Comment: Ошибка в ссылке «автора» замечена верно. Только указывать «:80» в http-ссылке не обязательно — это номер порта по умолчанию.

Answer (score 1):

В общем, это заняло у меня много времени, но я всё же добился своего. По совету @Eugene Krivenja я закрыл порты `1400-1500`, ещё раз проверил перенаправление с `80` на `1450` - всё верно. Пытался после этого зайти на сервер - ошибка `ECONNREFUSED` всё равно возникала, но уже не сразу, а через 20-30 секунд. Ну, я тогда начал действовать кардинально: немного изменил код сервера, очистил и пересобрал проект (на всякий случай, лишний раз не помешает); обновил прошивку роутера и снова сделал перенаправление с порта `80` на `1450` для конкретного IP. Скрин настроек роутера после действий над ним:

[image: Скрин]

Затем я запустил приложение-сервер и попытался зайти на него с клиента. Что, собственно, прошло успешно:

[image: Скрин]

Ну и на "сервере" появились соответствующие сообщения:

[image: Скрин]

**Итог.** Мне так и не удалось выяснить, что же стало причиной недоступности сервера, однако у меня есть 2 подозрения:

1. Проблема с прошивкой на роутере
2. Мои кривые руки и невозможность для меня сделать всё правильно с первого раза.

...но всё же, после моих радикальных действий сервер запустился и я этому очень рад.

P.S. Если возникнет вопрос, мол "Далеко ли ты уйдёшь на 480 Мб оперативки", то отвечу сразу - мне просто было интересно сделать свой "сервер" на Android, кроме как "Hello world" применения я ему не знаю.

P.P.S Небольшая заметка для тех, кто тоже захочет так поэкспериментировать: **не** выбирайте для своего сервера порт меньше 1024 - Android не позволит это сделать.

Comment: Очень похоже на баг прошивки, такое часто случается.